# Tab styles in Max Mega Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, megamenu

I hope that some can help me: I am trying to add a gray line in an active tab so that it gives the effect in the attached image:

[See Image](https://ibb.co/Mp3J7vb)

There will be an option within the mega menu to do it or there will be some style that can be modified?

Updated post:

This is the CSS solution:

```
/** center line **/
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-tabbed > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {
    border-right: 0px solid #ACC1D6;
}

#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-tabbed > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu {
    border-left: 3px solid #acc1d6;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

/*+ Style of every single item of the menu, I only put one here, only change the ID **/
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li#mega-menu-item-254944 > a.mega-menu-link:hover {
    border-radius:12px;
    width:45%;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please provide your code also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry I will try to be more detailed in the next post. I was finally able to find the solution, using quite a bit of css. I put it here in case someone needs something similar.